# Reflexivity carried to the lesser norm

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

If $(X, \|\cdot\|_{1})$ is a reflexive Banach space and $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ is a norm on $X$ such that $\|\cdot\|_{2} \leq \|\cdot\|_{1}$, is $(X, \|\cdot\|_{2})$ also reflexive?

Answer (score 0):

By the Open Mapping Theorem, $(X,||\cdot||_1)$ and $(X,||\cdot||_2)$ are isomorphic, so $(X,||\cdot||_2)$ is reflexive too